# How to Enhance at Runtime for the JavaAsssist Generated Pojo

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I have generated dynamic pojo in Javaassist, I want to enhance that pojo because of the JDO MetaData file is searching the the definition of generated pojo.

Below line of code is working fine in case of "com.Customer" pojo exist physically. But I am trying to enhance the generated dynamic pojo (Ex: "com.Customer" by using java assist) like below. In this case it is not working fine

```
JDOEnhancer enhancer = JDOHelper.getEnhancer();
enhancer.setVerbose(false);
enhancer.addClasses("com.Customer");
enhancer.enhance();
```

JDO Enhancer in Data Nucleus is not finding the definition of generated dynamic pojo(com.Customer) by using javaasssit.

Is it possible to enhance generated dynamic pojo(Ex: com.Customer which is generated by using javaasssit) before talking with JDO?

I will wait for your valuble answer.

Thanks,
Pavan

Answer (score 0):

DataNucleus documentation covers that, with a link to the DN Wiki
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/jdo/enhancer.html#api